# Auto initializing multiple types to specific values with out explicit declaration

Tags: c++

Besides the three examples and situations I mention below, is there a way to define a variable of let's say `int, float, double` without using the `= operator` and automatically initializing it whenever that type is declared to a specific value such as zero. Possibly through the use of a macro or another endeavor to bypass default functionality.

Which would then allow

```
int a; // Zero
```

Instead of

```
int a = 0;
int a{};
```

I am under the impression that default initialization is performed in three situations:

- When a variable with automatic, static, or thread-local storage
  duration is declared with no initializer;
- When an object with dynamic storage duration is created by a new-expression with no initializer or when an object is created by a new-expression with the initializer consisting of an empty pair of parentheses (until C++03);
- When a base class or a non-static data member is not mentioned in a constructor initializer list and that constructor is called.

I have attempted similar solutions such as overloading typecasts.

```
class Int
{
 private:
  int value;
 public:
  explicit Int(int v = 0) : value(v) {}
  explicit operator int() const { return this->value; }
};
```

Comment: Variables with automatic storage class with no initializers **most definitely** do not have default initialization performed for them, if they are of fundamental types.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I am still new to C++ and are you saying there is no way to use a macro or another endeavor to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: This is a very extensive topic, I suggest you read it at the reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization). I found out myself while reading this that I don't know enough.

Comment: One of the examples on the cppreference page for implicit conversion happens to be a generic version of your workaround: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion (see "zero_init"). But it's difficult to imagine how useful this is.